# how to display arrayof object data in table format using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactstrap, react-modal

```
i have two arrays of objects
fetch1= [{
    "A": 10
    "X": mac
},
{
    "A": 20
    "X": Hp
}]
fetch2=[{
    "B": 30
    "Y": windows
},
{
    "B":40
    "Y": macfee
}]
```

Output should be like table

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 30 |
| 20 | 40 |

First "A" column in a table should display 10 & 30.
Second "B" column in a table should display 20 & 40.
Example:

```
 <ModalBody>
                <Table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>A</th>
                      <th>B</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    {fetch1.map(obj => {
                      return <tr >{obj.A}</tr>;
                   })}                      
                   {fetch2.map(obj => {
                      return <td >{obj.B}</td>;
                   })}
                   </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
              </ModalBody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. Modified my code for your situation. I also added some checks in case the arrays are different sizes.  If they are we set default values `{A: -1, B: -1}`.  You can remove the additional code if you don't need it.

The most important line would be this `({...(smallestArray[index] ? smallestArray[index] : {A: -1, B: -1}), ...val});` where we merge the two arrays into one.

```
const genericTable = (props) => {
  const fetch1 = props.fetch1;
  const fetch2 = props.fetch2;
  // if arrays can be different sizes, don't know if this is your case
  const largestArray = fetch1.length > fetch2.length? fetch1 : fetch2;
  const smallestArray = fetch1.length > fetch2.length? fetch2 : fetch1;
  const newArray = largestArray.map((val, index) => 
      ({...(smallestArray[index] ? smallestArray[index] : {A: -1, B: -1}), ...val});
  return (
    <ModalBody >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {newArray.map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}> // change index key
            <td>{item.A}</td>
            <td>{item.B}</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```